Sum of nth roots to powers
I would like to calculate this sum :
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\omega^{k^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}e^{\frac{2ik^2π}{n}}
$$
I tried variables switching and some others tricks but no results...
I tried searching for a pattern to.
I wanna use the formula to calculate the sum of geometric series but I can't since the quantity depends on k.

Let $\zeta$ be a $p$’th root of units. It may help that Gauss showed $$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\zeta^{k^2}=\begin{cases}\sqrt p, p\equiv_4 1\\i\sqrt p, p\equiv_4 3 \end{cases}$$
